# Problema no carregamento do google Maps em aplicação web

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Tenho um site hospedado, e uso a Google Maps JavaScript API na aplicação. O problema que está acontecendo, é que o maps não carrega sempre, muitas das vezes é necessário ficar atualizando a página para em alguma das tentativas ele carregar corretamente.  Em nenhum momento a API aponta algum erro no console do navegador.

Já gerei a chave da API em console.developers.google.com/apis/.

Vale ressaltar que em localhost o maps funciona perfeitamente, sempre carrega (chave da API do localhost diferente da do site hospedado).

Já aconteceu algo parecido com alguém, alguma ideia do que possa ser?

Obrigado!

Comment: Você está utilizando alguma versão especifica? Consegue passar o link da versão que está em uso? Seria essa: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/adding-a-google-map ?

Comment: Com esse comando javascript "google.maps.version" obtive a versão do Google Maps JavaScript API usado na minha aplicação, que retornou "3.30.10"

Comment: Consegue postar o código para darmos uma olhada? Você seguiu o exemplo disponível em: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/adding-a-google-map ?